# deny specific number(0) on rails 3 numeric validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, numeric

I can't figure out how to deny only 0 from my validation. jQuery is not an option and :other_than doesn't exist in rails 3.0

```
validates_numericality_of :quantity,:only_integer=>true, :message=>"message"
```

tryed

```
:greater_than=>0, :less_than=>0
```

denies both negative and positive values, instead of allowing both;

```
:if=> Proc.new{|sc| sc.quantity!=0}
```

behave if this line doesn't exist(maybe syntax error that i can't identify)

```
:other_than=>0
```

doesn't exist in Rails v3.0

```
:if=> :test

def test
  !(:quantity==0)
end
```

same as the other :if statement

i'm trying to block the "save" of the form if the input=0

Comment: Can you show us your code? What did you try? What do you want to achieve? What's the context of this question?

Comment: edited with more info, thx for the attention

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true }, exclusion: [0]
```

Comment: your syntax gave me Rails' syntax error, and when i tryedo to adapt it didn't work(the 0 passed through validation) obs: when i leave the field empty, but i managed to clear the field before submit with a jQuery...

Comment: I don't know what to tell you (because you didn't give any more details of the error), but the above code worked fine for me in 3.0.20.

Comment: sorry, for i'm in incredibly hurry so i failed to write down the error, my rails is 3.0.10 and i chose the first solution that i found, wich was a jQuery using the "blur()" method to wipe the 0 from the input when it loses focus, when i have time i'll try to reproduce the error and give you more details.
i'm really grateful for your effort to help me and trully sorry for not being able to give you what you asked right now :(